# How can you set a value in an update statement based on 2 parameters?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

At the moment I have a store procedure that has an update statement with approx 40 values that are updated. Some of them only update if the input isn't null using COALESCE(). I was wondering if I can also do something similar but based on the input of another parameter as well as itself. For example:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FirstName = @FirstName,
    LastName = @LastName,
    JobNumber = (IF @MyMainParameter IS NOT NULL
                     COALESCE(@JobNumber, JobNumber)
                 ELSE
                     JobNumber)
WHERE ...
```

Obviously this doesn't work but in this example I only want to update job number if @MyMainParameter isn't null and if the @JobNumber parameter isn't null.

Obviously I could just do a separate update statement based on whether my @MyMainParameter is null or not, such as:

```
IF @MyMainParameter IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET JobNumber = COALESCE(@JobNumber, JobNumber)
    WHERE...
END
```

However, it doesn't seem optimal to be doing 2 update statements if I can do just 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was having a brain freeze. I can obviously do this quite easily using the CASE WHEN statement like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FirstName = @FirstName,
    LastName = @LastName,
    JobNumber = CASE WHEN @MyMainParameter IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(@JobNumber, JobNumber) ELSE JobNumber END
WHERE ...
```